# How to display horizontal line for only in particular page in wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

```
        /*I am using the wordpress i designed about ,contact and subscribe page.i want to display banner image  for about and contact page, i don't want it in subscribe page instead of that i want put horizontal line after the header logo section */

        //like this my display in about and contact page
        <header>
         <logo section>

         <Banner section>
        </header>
        <body>
         <content section>
        </body>

        //in subscribe page

        <header>
         <logo section>

         <hr></hr>
        </header>
        <body>
         <content section>
        </body>

        //code is below

        <?php if ( !is_page('subscription') ) {  ?>

 <div class="linebar" style="width:100%;border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(238, 238, 238);">   </div>
<?php } ?> 

                    <div class="header-cover section bg no-padding">

                        <div class="header section" style="background:#ecbf0c">



                             <div class="header-inner section-inner"> 


                            </div>  <!-- /header-inner -->

                        </div> <!-- /header -->

                    </div> <!-- /bg-dark -->

                    <div class="navigation section no-padding bg-dark">

                        <div class="navigation-inner section-inner">

                            <div class="toggle-container hidden">

                                <div class="nav-toggle toggle">

                                    <div class="bar"></div>
                                    <div class="bar"></div>
                                    <div class="bar"></div>

                                    <div class="clear"></div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="search-toggle toggle">

                                    <div class="metal"></div>
                                    <div class="glass"></div>
                                    <div class="handle"></div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="clear"></div>

                            </div> <!-- /toggle-container -->

                            <div class="blog-search hidden">

                                <?php get_search_form(); ?>

                            </div>




    </div>
</div>

    /*this my code so help to resolve my problem i want to display the horizontal line in the subscribe page .*/

//first logo section that contains the left side logo and right side menus 

//next hr line then i want to display subscribe form 

/*so please help me to solve this problem  .i don't know where to place the php code to hide the content in for particular page instead of that add the new content for that */
```

// i have mentioned the code above

//i want to display the horizontal line or the content on that place

```
/*so please help me to solve this problem  .i don't know where to place the php code to hide the content in for particular page instead of that add the new content for that */
```

// i have mentioned the code above

//i want to display the horizontal line or the content on that place

Comment: linebar is the horizontal line that you'd like to display?

Comment: yes ,line bar is class name for that hr line..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want it to display on when

```
<?php if ( !is_page('subscription') )
echo '<div class="linebar" style="width:100%; border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(238, 238, 238);"></div>';
?>
```

try that..

assuming you want a div to display when something is true, you do this

';

that will display div is e is true and echo no if e is false.

?>

Comment: it is  display except the subscription page and banner also displayed

Comment: the above code is supposed to work, maybe your is_page function may not be functioning correctly, if possible, please post part of your is_page code..